# LibTiff.net doesn't expose Tiff2Pdf?

Tags: vb.net, libtiff.net

I'm trying to move away from using a command line app to convert TIFF to PDF; in doing so, I've installed LibTiff.net and tried to convert a file using their [provided example](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/).

Even using the sample exactly as they put it, it seems like I can't find the Tiff2Pdf function. I've tried `Tiff2Pdf`, `BitMiracle.Tiff2Pdf`, `BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff2Pdf`, etc.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO
Imports BitMiracle

Namespace BitMiracle.LibTiff.Samples
    Public NotInheritable Class ConvertTiffToPdf
        Public Shared Sub Main()
            Dim inputFile As String = "Sample Data\multipage.tif"
            Dim outputFile As String = "output.pdf"

            Dim arguments As String() = New String() {"-o", outputFile, "-p", "A4", inputFile}
            Tiff2Pdf.Program.Main(arguments)

            Process.Start(outputFile)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Is there another reason why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you download the binaries package from [here](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/), it will contain `Tiff2Pdf.exe`. As crazy as it sounds you need to add this exe as reference for access to BitMiracle.Tiff2Pdf. You can find the source code of this utility in its GitHub [repository](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Tiff2Pdf).

Comment: I know this is a very old topic but I cannot find the binaries using that link.